# knockout.js, knockout-sortable, and default text

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm using knockout.js and [`knockout-sortable`](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable), and I'm currently trying to get some default text inside of the `sortable` parent element if there are no elements in the array passed into the `sortable` binding.

This is related to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864910/knockout-default-text-when-foreach-is-empty), but different due to my requirement: I cannot have the text outside of the parent element. Meaning, this:

```
<div data-bind="if: pets().length > 0">These are the pets:</div>
<div data-bind="if: pets().length == 0">There aren't any pets. To add a pet...</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: pets">
```

... is not valid for me. The text needs to be contained inside of the foreach loop so it also functions as a drop area. I did take a look at the [`knockout-punches`](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/) library but I haven't come up with a solution using it yet. I'm open to a pure knockout solution or a plugin.

My code currently looks like this:

```
<div class="my-drop" data-bind="foreach: { template: 'myTemplate', data: myContainerList}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new binding or extend `foreach` to show something when the array is empty. Here's an example that extends `foreach`.

```
var origForeachUpdate = ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update;
ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update = function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor();
    if (options.defaultText) {
        var array = ko.unwrap(options.data);
        if (!array || !array.length) {
            element.innerText = options.defaultText;
        } else if (element.innerText == options.defaultText) {
            element.innerText = "";
        }
    }
    origForeachUpdate.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/Z7BeM/

Comment: While this was the solution I accepted, I also created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/seiyria/7831726) detailing how I got it to work specifically with knockout-sortable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual-element binding:

```
<div>
<span data-bind="if: pets().length > 0">These are the pets:</span>
<span data-bind="if: pets().length == 0">There aren't any pets. To add a pet...</span>
<!-- ko foreach: pets -->
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Virtual bindings are the standard way to handle the case where you need a list that includes some fixed items as well as variable items.

Comment: That doesn't quite work out, as I need the messages inside of where the `foreach` would be, as I stated in the question. If the messages are outside of the `foreach` loop, they can't function as a drop-zone for the `sortable` element that the loop creates.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help? It generates a copy of the template that isn't shown here, as it's just a lot of HTML/knockout. What I need to do is generate a default message when there are no elements in the `observableArray` backing that `sortable` call.

Comment: The problem is that if `pets` is empty, `foreach pets` won't produce any output; that's just the way `foreach` works. Nobody can do anything more than guess unless we can see what you're actually generating (just strip it down to a simplified case that includes the `sortable` binding).