# How to replace a default date with an empty string

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a html span that display a date using moment.js in the page:

```
<span data-bind="text: moment(new Date(dueDate())).format('MM/DD/YYYY')"></span>
```

It's working fine apart if the `dueDate()` property is an empty string, If it's an empty string I'm getting:

> 01/01/1900

How can avoid that?

This is the entire div:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <ul>
      <li>DATE <span data-bind="text: moment(new Date(sDate())).format('MM/DD/YYYY')"></span></li>
      <li>Due date <span></span><span data-bind="text: moment(new Date(dueDate())).format('MM/DD/YYYY')"></span>
           <p>Days Remaining: <span class="days-remaining" data-bind="text: daysRemaining"></span></p>
      </li>
      <li>Date 2 <span></span><span data-bind="text: moment(new Date(date2())).format('MM/DD/YYYY')"></span>
           <p>Days Remaining: <span class="days-remaining" data-bind="text: daysRemaining"></span></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: use a if condition, test if the string is empty

Comment: I'm not sure how to add an `if` in this context.

Comment: You can check the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577078/knockout-js-data-bind-text-default-value

Comment: `data-bind="text: dueDate()? moment(dueDate(), format).format('MM/DD/YYYY')"`. Also, I'd suggest you to make `dueDate` a string variable and process values in  your `vm` instead of `view`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add a check. If value exists, then parse value, else show blank.

```js
this.getDateInFormat = function(str){
  var d = moment(str, DEFAULT_FORMAT);
  return str && d.isValid() ? d.format('MM/DD/YYYY') : '';
}
```

As commented before, you should move all parsing logic to your viewModel. This way your code is generic and your view is clean.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/nz70sfej/1/).

Comment: What is the `DEFAULT_FORMAT` parameter?

Comment: Moment constructor expects a format if you are parsing string. Its just a variable that holds `"DD/MM/YYYY"`. You should read code in fiddle

Comment: I didn't notice the Fiddle, working, thank you so much!